# Cinemachine camera does not switch when brain is outside main camera

Tags: unity, camera, cinemachine

I have a Main Camera object set up like the screenshot below:

[image: Camera component]

And another game object with Cinemachine Brain.

[image: Cinemachine brain]

So, this way the main camera works but the timeline cinemachine tracks doesn't switch cameras.

If I put Cinemachine Brain inside the same main camera game object, then it works.

So, is this the correct way to use a Cinemachine Brain? Is it a must to have it on the same game object as the Main Camera?